# raw type pass super to sub

Tags: java, generics

according this quote form http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/javagenerics_chap05/index.html?page=2

> Every parameterized type is a subtype of the corresponding raw type,
>   so a value of the parameterized type can be passed where a raw type is
>   expected. ***Usually, it is an error to pass a value of a supertype where
>   a value of its subtype is expected, but Java does permit a value of a
>   raw type to be passed where a parameterized type is expected—however,***
>   it flags this circumstance by generating an unchecked conversion
>   warning. For instance, you can assign a value of type `Stack<E>` to a
>   variable of type `Stack`, since the former is a subtype of the latter.
>   You can also assign a value of type Stack to a variable of type
>   `Stack<E>`, but this will generate an unchecked conversion warning.

this code must be true

```
public class Trial 
{
    static void t(Stack<Integer> a )
    {

    }

   public static void main( String[] args ) 
   {
       t( new s());
   }
}

class s{

}
class Stack< T > extends s {
}
```

it's an error at **t( new s());**
I'm asking why give me error , not how to solve the problem !

Comment: You are confusing generics with inheritance.  That quote is evidently referring to generics, whereas your example is demonstrating inheritance.

Comment: read the quote above please

Comment: If you read your quote carefully raw type is `Stack` not `s`

Comment: Stack<T> is parametrized (sub)type of Stack

Comment: @Aladdin consider reading the quote in your question.  Your example in no way matches the quote.  The quote talks about type Stack and type Stack<E>.  Notice that Stack<E> and Stack are both type Stack.  Your exmple uses type S and type Stack<T>.  Notice that type S is not a Stack.  You can not pass an object of type S as a parameter in a method call that expects a type Stack.

Comment: my concentration is how to use up Generic Library with Legacy Client by raw type

Answer (score 1):

> Usually, it is an error to pass a value of a supertype where a value
>   of its subtype is expected, ***but Java does permit a value of a raw type
>   to be passed where a parameterized type is expected***
>
> ...
>
> I'm asking why give me error , not how to solve the problem

You get the error because the exception does not apply - the exception only applies to passing the ***raw type*** value where the parameterized type is expected.  `s` is not the raw type of `Stack<T>`; `Stack` is the raw type of `Stack<T>`.

You can pass a value of type `Stack<T>` or you can pass a value of raw type `Stack` with a warning, but you cannot pass value of type `s` because its an error to pass the value of a supertype where a subtype is expected and `s` is not the raw type of the expected type `Stack<T>`.

Comment: my concentration is how to use up Generic Library with Legacy Client by raw type ..can you give me an example of that ?

Comment: I agree with @Joni - given the information provided, I don't see how you can make it work the way you want.

Comment: in any way by using raw type

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is no way to make this code work. You can make it compile by casting `s` to `Stack` in the method call, but then it will fail in runtime:

```
public class Trial 
{
    static void t(Stack<Integer> a )
    {

    }

   public static void main( String[] args ) 
   {
       // Compiles but throws a ClassCastException
       // because an "s" is not a "Stack".
       t((Stack) new s());
   }
}

class s{

}
class Stack< T > extends s {
}
```